# Nodejs as static library Link errors

Tags: c++, node.js, openssl, static-libraries, chromium-embedded

I compiled nodejs as static library. I also added an exe project in nodejs solution and used that library in that and it worked.

I then tried to use nodejs library with libcef. In the libcef solution i gave options of

```
Add additional library directory: # C:\blah\chromium\chromium\src\node\node\$(Configuration)\lib
Add additional library: # node.lib
Add additoinal include dir: # C:\blah\chromium\chromium\src\node\node\src
```

Then i tried to build libcef and it is giving 330 linker errors like:

```
245>     Creating library ..\build\Debug\lib\libcef.lib and object ..\build\Debug\lib\libcef.exp
245>node.lib(node_crypto.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ERR_error_string_n referenced in function "class v8::Handle<class v8::Value> __cdecl node::crypto::ThrowCryptoErrorHelper(unsigned long,bool)" (?ThrowCryptoErrorHelper@crypto@node@@YA?AV?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@v8@@K_N@Z)
245>node.lib(node_crypto.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_free referenced in function "class v8::Handle<class v8::Value> __cdecl node::crypto::GetSSLCiphers(class v8::Arguments const &)" (?GetSSLCiphers@crypto@node@@YA?AV?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@v8@@ABVArguments@4@@Z)
245>node.lib(node_crypto.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SSL_CTX_sess_set_new_cb referenced in function "protected: static class v8::Handle<class v8::Value> __cdecl node::crypto::SecureContext::Init(class v8::Arguments const &)" (?Init@SecureContext@crypto@node@@KA?AV?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@v8@@ABVArguments@5@@Z)
```

and others like

```
241>node.lib(stream_wrap.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _uv_write referenced in function "public: static class v8::Handle<class v8::Value> __cdecl node::StreamWrap::WriteBuffer(class v8::Arguments const &)" (?WriteBuffer@StreamWrap@node@@SA?AV?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@v8@@ABVArguments@4@@Z)
241>node.lib(stream_wrap.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _uv_shutdown referenced in function "public: static class v8::Handle<class v8::Value> __cdecl node::StreamWrap::Shutdown(class v8::Arguments const &)" (?Shutdown@StreamWrap@node@@SA?AV?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@v8@@ABVArguments@4@@Z)
241>node.lib(stream_wrap.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _uv_write2 referenced in function "private: static class v8::Handle<class v8::Value> __cdecl node::StreamWrap::WriteStringImpl<0>(class v8::Arguments const &)" (??$WriteStringImpl@$0A@@StreamWrap@node@@CA?AV?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@v8@@ABVArguments@3@@Z)
241>node.lib(node_stat_watcher.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _uv_fs_poll_init referenced in function "protected: __thiscall node::StatWatcher::StatWatcher(void)" (??0StatWatcher@node@@IAE@XZ)
241>node.lib(node_stat_watcher.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _uv_fs_poll_start referenced in function "protected: static class v8::Handle<class v8::Value> __cdecl node::StatWatcher::Start(class v8::Arguments const &)" (?Start@StatWatcher@node@@KA?AV?$Handle@VValue@v8@@@v8@@ABVArguments@4@@Z)
241>node.lib(node_stat_watcher.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _uv_fs_poll_stop referenced in function "private: void __thiscall node::StatWatcher::Stop(void)" (?Stop@StatWatcher@node@@AAEXXZ)
```

I added all the libraries in node\Release\lib like openssl.lib.

And **Link errors has reduced** to only:

```
241>nss_static.lib(sha_fast.obj) : error LNK2005: _SHA1_Update already defined in openssl.lib(sha1dgst.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(seed.obj) : error LNK2005: _SEED_set_key already defined in openssl.lib(seed.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(seed.obj) : error LNK2005: _SEED_encrypt already defined in openssl.lib(seed.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(seed.obj) : error LNK2005: _SEED_decrypt already defined in openssl.lib(seed.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(seed.obj) : error LNK2005: _SEED_ecb_encrypt already defined in openssl.lib(seed_ecb.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(seed.obj) : error LNK2005: _SEED_cbc_encrypt already defined in openssl.lib(seed_cbc.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(sha512.obj) : error LNK2005: _SHA256_Update already defined in openssl.lib(sha256.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(sha512.obj) : error LNK2005: _SHA224_Update already defined in openssl.lib(sha256.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(sha512.obj) : error LNK2005: _SHA512_Update already defined in openssl.lib(sha512.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(sha512.obj) : error LNK2005: _SHA384_Update already defined in openssl.lib(sha512.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(md5.obj) : error LNK2005: _MD5_Update already defined in openssl.lib(md5_dgst.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(alghmac.obj) : error LNK2005: _HMAC_Init already defined in openssl.lib(hmac.obj)
241>nss_static.lib(alghmac.obj) : error LNK2005: _HMAC_Update already defined in openssl.lib(hmac.obj)
```

How can i resolve them ?

Comment: Looks like you're missing OpenSSL ...

Comment: I looked into node/Debug/lib dir and it has openssl.lib and others. I would try by adding them too.

Comment: Looks like you have too many libraries now.  Were you linking with nss_static.lib before?  It looks like that library already has OpenSSL in it.